How can I use an indexed access type of the value type of an index signature as parameter type?
In the following script, there is an error in the Line f3(p1, true). The error is:

Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T["a"][string]'.(2345)

type BaseType = {
  a: {[key: string]: boolean};
}

function f1() { 
  let p1: BaseType = {
    a: {
        b: true,
    }
  }

  f2(p1, true);
}

function f2<T extends BaseType>(p1: T, p2: T["a"][string]) {
  f3(p1, true);
}

function f3<T extends BaseType>(p1: T, p2: T["a"][string]) {
  console.log(p1)
  console.log(typeof p2)
}

f1()

There is no error in the following script:
type BaseType = {
  a: {b: boolean};
}

function f1() { 
  let p1: BaseType = {
    a: {
        b: true,
    }
  }

  f2(p1, true);
}

function f2<T extends BaseType>(p1: T, p2: T["a"]["b"]) {
  f3(p1, true);
}

function f3<T extends BaseType>(p1: T, p2: T["a"]["b"]) {
  console.log(p1)
  console.log(typeof p2)
}

f1()

Why does TypeScript throw an error in the first script, but not in the second script?

The first is an error because it's quite possible for T["a"][string] to be false and not true, as shown here. Of course the second should also be an error for that reason, as shown here and it's not... TypeScript tends to lose genericness when doing operations with multiple indexed accesses, and it's hard to know exactly why. (see next comment)

(see prev comment) So... are you really asking about the inconsistency (which might take a deep dive into the compiler and/or github issues) or are you asking "how can I do X" as the title implies (which might need an [edit] to describe why T is generic if you assume T["a"]["b"] is true)?
